# Integrating Sencha Touch with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sencha-touch-2

I have a website which need a mobile version.
I decided to use Sencha Touch 2.1 to create it.

I found the [following Gem](https://github.com/AlexVangelov/sencha-touch-rails) but it is clearly outdated.

So my question is do you know an easy way to integrate Sencha Touch with Rails Assets Pipeline?

The fact that the app needs to be built made me put it in the public directory for now.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think Sencha Touch is a good use case in this scenario.

For a mobile version of a web application I would recommend switching to a framework with a responsive grid system such as Zurb foundation or Twitter bootstrap.

If you are still insisting on using Sencha Touch I would recommend creating a subdomain, such as http://mobile.domain.com and then serving the static files from something like S3, you can then use Sencha Touch to consume your Rails API.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. The use of Sencha Touch is motivated by two things. First I only need a small subset of the feature the desktop version has and second, I want to learn how to use Sencha. Anyway, thank you for Zurb, I didn't know this framework before.